# There is a bug when you Move/Re-Open/Move Again

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration

I made an early morning before coffee mistake with [this](https://superuser.com/questions/32766/stdcin-with-qtcreator-on-mac) question. The question was meant to go to SO however:

- I closed it to go to SF
- Re-opened the question on SU
- Moved it to SO

However it still states migrated to SF and the links point to the SF question not the SO question. It seems re-opening the question does not remove the migrated to message.

I have manually placed a link to the SO question

Comment: The link you've added does not work. Was it been moved again?

Comment: @John - I'm guessing it is deleted; so only visible to 10k+ or ♦ users.

Comment: To be fair, this is only a mistake that can only be made by a very few people... as you'd presumably need to unlock it etc.

Comment: Wow! Moved to SO to get deleted there. Be a mod must be fun :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll have to manually manipulate the database to fix this. May take a few days until I have time to get to it.

Comment: No problem. It should be rare for this to happen however worth noting.